# What are is most basic set of git command you would teach first?

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm using mercurial with bitbucket to synchronize my code between computers, there's only me using it, I could totally use a centralized protocol like SVN, but I just like mercurial.

Things are easy with mercurial, hg add/com/up/push/pull/status and I'm ready to go. I often get in trouble with merges when I forgot to pull first, but I manage to solve it.

git is known to be quite sophisticated, and I was quite fine using mercurial, but I still just want to learn the very basics of git.

What are the least amount of command any git beginner use when he has a working git repo he wants to push and pull onto ? For example, what are the equivalent sets of commands of hg status/add/com/push/pull/up ?

Comment: Read at least chapter two and three of the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) to have a good foundation.

Comment: The equivalents are almost the same, except `up`. And first of all you need to `clone`, but there's nothing more to learn about *that*. The official book is free http://git-scm.com/book, and there's also this: http://try.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very basic commands which you will need to experiment on git are

1. `git clone`
2. `git add`
3. `git commit`
4. `git push`

However, git is a very powerful SCM tool and provides lot of flexibilities and each git user has his/her own set of favorite commands which usually increase over time. I would recommend you to read http://git-scm.com/book and also experiment by creating your own repository and trying out various git commands on it, you will learn a lot. You can also refer to the help page by passing the argument `--help` to a command. The help pages are quite comprehensively written.

For example `git clone --help`

Answer (score 3):

My 5 most used commands are:

1. `git add .` //Add all edited files to staging
2. `git commit -am 'Message'` // commit everything changed
3. `git log` // check out the log of commit
4. `git diff` --name-status HEAD^ HEAD // See what you changed on last commit
5. `git checkout -- file` // undo changes to a file so you don't commit it.

And for working with remote repositories:

1. `git clone $url` //$url is a git url like this git@github.com:account/repo.git
2. `git push origin master` // origin is the name you give the the remote and master is the branch name
3. `git pull origin master` // save as above